# mousemove offset X/Y wrong in Chrome when used on a SVG text element

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg, dom-events, mousemove

http://jsfiddle.net/g0bq6af6/2/

SVG

```
<svg height="750" version="1.1" width="830" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="925 890 1363 1192">
  <g>
    <text x="975" y="1795" style="font-size: 816px;">foo</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Javascript:

```
x = document.getElementById('coords');

document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].addEventListener('mousemove', function(a) {

  x.innerHTML = (a.offsetX === undefined) ? (a.layerX + ' ' + a.layerY) : (a.offsetX + ' ' + a.offsetY);

});
```

I bind mousemove on `<svg>` and print the `offsetX` and `offsetY`. When the mouse is on `<text>` the coordinates are way wrong, ie -755, -925 instead of the expected 215, 114.

`layerX` and `layerY` are correct however.

This problem is in Chrome. Opera gives the correct result. IE is still untested. Firefox does not have offset X/Y and gives a correct result through layer X/Y.

Can anyone please explain this?

I have tried using jQuery to achieve it's normalizing effect but the result is same.

**UPDATE**

I updated the JSFiddle and added a `<circle>` to demonstrate that this behaviour is for the `<text>` element only.

View it here: http://jsfiddle.net/g0bq6af6/3/

Comment: One way to work around this is to add pointer-events: none on the `<text>`. And another one is of course to use the layer X/Y in Chrome. But I still want to understand why.

Comment: Maybe this is a bug in Chrome? If I get no answers here I'll report it as a possible bug.

Comment: offsetX/Y don't have a standard definition for SVG elements (since [they are defined relative to CSS box model padding area](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#dom-mouseevent-offsetx)), so you really should use another method for cross-browser compatibility as is.  That said, I have no idea why you're getting such large negative numbers.  The standard rule is to return pageX/Y if offsetX/Y can't be calculated, which should always be a positive number.